# How to define the type signature for objects have new method

Tags: typescript, types, constructor

I learned that `new()` is how we structurally type a class constructor in TypeScript, so how can we type an object that has `new` method, like:

```
const k = {
  new() {
    return '123'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no corresponding object literal syntax to define  an object literal with `new`. You can use a class expression:

```
const k = class {
  constructor () {

  }
}

new k()
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1jAvDYAbAhhCMDeBYAKBhXGgCcBXYKEMmACgEpdDjjWYBfQ7gwsAKYB3eEyA)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `new` is used to **instantiate** a class.

```js
const k = new MyClass();
```

To define the constructor of this class you have to use the `constructor` keyword.

```js
class MyClass1 {
  constructor() {
  }
}

const MyClass2 = class {
  constructor() {
  }
}

interface MyClass3 {
    constructor(): Function;  // should be Function *if* we want it generic
}
```

`MyClass1` and `MyClass2` are quite equivalent.

Be careful to `MyClass3`, you can't do something like `const k = new MyClass3()`. But you can do `const k: MyClass3 = new MyClass1()`. `MyClass3` is an interface, so you can use it only for typing nothing more.

Note that in Typescript when you define a class, it's also creating an interface. It's why a class can `implements` another class.

More info with TS doc:
[Class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)
[Interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

Comment: emm, when I try `const k: MyClass3 = new MyClass1()`, typescript emit an type error.

Comment: @L_K I made a playground http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAYwNghgzlAECyBPAwpGBGWBvYtYgHsA7KAFwCcBXEUg8gCgEptdYBfYD0YshFNKACZYAXnwCWeQiQrVaDZjjwcuASyKkApuQBmEEJr6poUAMyS8+HrJp0AXLABilIjVXEA3J2DcZsANYOSMYw5mJEmgDuRgLoTF5AA

Comment: oh I see, there may be a typo in `MyClass3`, `MyClass3` should be `{ constructor: Function }`. However, I still have doubts about the type signature for objects have new method.